# Python can't catch overridden NameError

Tags: python, exception, overriding, nameerror

How can you explain this:

This code is supposed to override the NameError and then catch it.

```
OldNameError = NameError
class NameError(OldNameError):
    pass

try:
    ccc
except NameError as e:
    print "hi"
```

Does not print "hi".
Instead, the output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try.py", line 6, in <module>
    ccc
NameError: name 'ccc' is not defined
```

But this code:

```
OldNameError = NameError
class NameError(OldNameError):
    pass

try:
    raise NameError("oo")
except NameError:
    print "hi"
```

Gives the output I wanted:

```
hi
```

What is the explanation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `except NameError`, you are saying you want to catch exceptions of the type of whatever `NameError` refers to at the moment you do the catching.  Since you changed what `NameError` is, you are trying to catch your new class.  But the exception that is raised is a "real" `NameError`, not your overriden one.

You can see this if you modify your except clause:

```
try:
    ccc
except Exception as e:
    print isinstance(e, NameError)
    print isinstance(e, OldNameError)
```

The output is:

```
False
True
```

. . . indicating that the raised exception is an OldNameError, not your new NameError.

You cannot change what kind of exception is raised due to an undefined name.  You can create something *called* NameError, but it will never be used unless you use it explicitly yourself (as you did in your second example).

Comment: Why can't I change what is raised? It must be defined somewhere and I should be able to override it, shouldn't I?

Comment: @EllaShar: It's not defined within Python code.  To change it, you would need to modify the Python iterpreter itself.  Why would you want to do this anyway?

Comment: Thanks. But what happens when I write `ccc` and it's not defined? How python "knows" which exception to raise?

Comment: @EllaShar: As I said, that behavior is built into the Python Interpreter.

Comment: @EllaShar: if it helps, you can imagine that there's a bit of code somewhere that takes a reference to the `NameError` class before the interpreter starts running any of your code. The exception is then thrown using this reference to the class, not using its name.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I get it now. So there is no way to change the exception that is thrown when an undefined name is written (or the way it works).

Comment: @EllaShar: Right.  Why do you feel you need to do that, though?

Comment: Mostly curiosity. But I also thought that it could be the answer to something I am trying to do and it's a challenge so I won't ask about it :)