# Python dynamic import speed

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def do_import(name):
    import imp

    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module(name)

    try:
        return imp.load_module(name, fp, pathname, description)
    finally:
        # Since we may exit via an exception, close fp explicitly.
        if fp:
            fp.close()
```

The above takes a few milliseconds per call to `do_import()` and I want it to be faster.
I am using Python 2.7.

Is there a way to achieve the same thing except import faster? I tried to use `imp.load_source` but I wasn't able to do so.

Is there another library I can use to dynamically import? I looked into `importlib` and `__import__` without success.

Comment: Takes e-3 per call? What does that mean?

Comment: You could check sys.modules to see if its already imported but this is as fast as you can do it.

Comment: I assume e-3 means 1 millisecond? What the heck are you doing where 1 millisecond presumably once or a few times per execution is too slow?

Comment: @tdelaney its all different .py files

Comment: @MartinValgur i do it to about 1000 different .py files which results in 10 seconds ish which is too slow for me

Comment: @ealeon Your original question didn't have units (seconds). There is no reason to scold someone for not understanding something which was at best implicit in your original wording.

Comment: Why do you have a thousand different Python files? What are you doing exactly? Why did you choose Python for something which requires sub-milliseconds execution time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 2.7: import performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41816404/python-2-7-import-performance)

Comment: @VincentSavard I agree - wanting to dynamically import so many modules that a millisecond per module is too slow sounds like somebody's trying to do the Wrong Thing and painted themselves into a corner.

Comment: @VincentSavard - I don't think that's a dup because evwn though the question is the same there is no accepted answer.

Comment: @tdelaney It doesn't matter when both questions are from the same person

Comment: @VincentSavard - That would have been worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

python does not support lazy loading of modules. [Some have tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21803555/python-cant-catch-overridden-nameerror) to override certain exceptions, which in theory could generate a signal to load a module only when a `NameError` is encountered, but builtin exceptions cannot be overridden (unless you change the cpython source and build yourself).

Building your own logic to handle imports can be done by searching `sys.modules` to make sure they're there and `__import__` to import a module by string.